# Dealing with non-English entity name

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to ng-repeat a few greek letters by using their entity name but the entity name, not the letter gets bound to the html. It seems like a simple issue but I have found very little on the literature about this.

```
var DemoCtrl = function($scope) {
    $scope.greekAlphabet = ['&Alpha;', '&Beta;', 
                            '&Gamma;', '&Delta;', '&Epsilon;'];
};
```

The resulting HTML looks like this:

```
&Alpha;
&Beta;
&Gamma;
&Delta;
&Epsilon;
```

and not like

> Α
>
> Β
>
> Γ
>
> Δ
>
> Ε

Here is a JSFiddle to illustrate the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/c3hHx/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bind HTML as unsafe.

JS:

```
var DemoCtrl = function ($scope, $sce) {
$scope.greekAlphabet = ['&Alpha;', '&Beta;',
    '&Gamma;', '&Delta;', '&Epsilon;'];
$scope.to_trusted = function (html_code) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(html_code);
}
};
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="letter in greekAlphabet" ng-bind-html="to_trusted(letter)">{{ letter }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

inlude the sanitize module in your app: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize.$sanitize

after that you may use

Comment: Although $sanitize would work, after investigating further I have seen that $sce is a better practice.